# What is this CSS in bootstrap doing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have some Jquery UI draggable span elements that, after adding Bootstrap 3.0 to my website have shrunk in height, this is a problem because they are part of a document tagging/positioning app of mine and need to stay the same height. I found the culprit to be:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In Bootstrap.css. If I comment out -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;, box-sizing: border-box; or -moz-box-sizing: border-box; individually my problem persists, but if comment out this entire style the height of my draggable elements return to their original height.

I can override this style like so to restore the height of my ui-draggable span elements:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

What is the difference between content-box and border-box?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=box+sizing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**content-box:** width, padding, border, margin are the individual contents in **content box model**

[image]
**border-box:**  the border box model includes border and padding inside the width.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you the visual images, every helpful, I have accepted your answer though both were very informative and helpful to me in my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule determines how an element's dimensions are computed, with `width` and `height` taking on different meanings depending on the value. Basically, it modifies the CSS box model.

`content-box` is default, and means "don't include `padding` or `border` in the values of `width` and `height`".

If you set it to `border-box`, it's the opposite; your `padding` and `border` sizes will be collapsed into the element's dimensions. Note that `margin` will not be (there is no `margin-box` value, so `margin` is always outside of an element's dimensions). For example, setting

```
width: 200px;
padding: 0 20px;
```

will mean that `40px` (`20px + 20px`) of that `200px` width will be consumed for the `margin`/`padding`, and only `160px` will be left for content width. With `content-box`, the content width would take up all `200px` of your `width` rule, and the `padding` would be added outside of the element's content as normal.

The likely reason behind the shotgun approach you found (setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on `*, *:before, *:after`) is because some people have found that `box-sizing: border-box;` is more intuitive than the default `content-box` value, as you know you will always have an element of the specified dimension (`width`/`height`) for layout purposes, no matter what `padding` or `border` sizes you have (`margin` will still affect layout). This view has been popularized by Paul Irish in [this blog post of his](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Note that the other rules in there are simply the vendor-specific rules, for versions of those vendors' browsers that didn't yet support the standard `box-sizing` rule.